# How to change default fonts in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, fonts, default

How can i change the default font settings in xubuntu? All i can find is the overall font settings in the appearance menu, i want to be able to set things like my monospace font for the terminal?

EDIT

On ubuntu, there is a settings menu, where you can edit fonts for individual purposes, for example, title font, window font, monospace font etc.

Im looking for a similar menu in xubuntu

Comment: ... maybe I'm not understanding the question ... open a terminal -  Edit Preferences - Appearance .  Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: updated for clarity

Answer (score 12):

I believe the font settings are all over the place in Xubuntu.
For the theme default font, > Applications > Settings > Settings Manager > Appearance > Fonts tab > Default Font -

[image]

For the window manager font(window title bar) > Applications > Settings > Settings Manager > Window Manager > Style > Title font -

[image]

For the Xfce Terminal, Open up the terminal,located > Applications > Accessories > Terminal Emulator, go to > Edit > Preferences > Appearance > Font -

[image]